# asp.net identity failing on login-callback

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have my API, react spa app in one project, and am integrating asp.net identity into the same project.  I have scaffolded it and everything works when I go to the identity pages.  If I go to Identity/Account/Login I can register and login to a user just fine.  However, when I attempt to log in from one of my pages, I get the following error after the login-callback when accessing https://localhost:44393/connect/token

```
System.NotSupportedException: IDX10634: Unable to create the SignatureProvider.
Algorithm: 'System.String', SecurityKey: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey'
 is not supported. The list of supported algorithms is available here: https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/supported-algorithms
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateSignatureProvider(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures, Boolean cacheProvider)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForSigning(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean cacheProvider)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForSigning(SecurityKey key, String algorithm)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JwtTokenUtilities.CreateEncodedSignature(String input, SigningCredentials signingCredentials)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(SecurityToken token)
   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenCreationService.CreateJwtAsync(JwtSecurityToken jwt)
   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenCreationService.CreateTokenAsync(Token token)
   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenService.CreateSecurityTokenAsync(Token token)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.CreateAccessTokenAsync(ValidatedTokenRequest request)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.ProcessAuthorizationCodeRequestAsync(TokenRequestValidationResult request)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.ProcessAsync(TokenRequestValidationResult request)
   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint.ProcessTokenRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint.ProcessAsync(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events, IBackChannelLogoutService backChannelLogoutService)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events, IBackChannelLogoutService backChannelLogoutService)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I have wrapped my route in the default AuthorizeRoute componet like this :

```
<AuthorizeRoute path="/Settings" render={(props) => (<SettingsMenu {...props} cloud={this.state.cloud} evaluation={this.state.evaluation}/>)} />
```

and otherwise have not changed the code from the identity react pages.

I assume I am missing something in my configuration.  But I built the sample identityreact project and that seems to work fine.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the log it says

```
Algorithm: 'System.String',
```

That looks like a bug, what algorithm do you try to use?

The algorithm should be one of the one listed [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/Supported-Algorithms)

To create a signing key, you typically use the openssl command line tool to generate the signing key and also wrap it into a .pkcs12/.pfx file.  If you use Azure Key Vault, it can generate it for you as well. Adding and importing the key into IdentityServer can be tricky.

I typically use this code to import the key into .NET:

```
    private static SecurityKey LoadEcdsaKey()
    {
        var ecdsaCert = new X509Certificate2("es256.pfx", "mypassword");
        SecurityKey ecdsaPrivateKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(ecdsaCert.GetECDsaPrivateKey());
        return ecdsaPrivateKey;
    }
```

See this [article](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Using-ECDSA-in-IdentityServer4) on how to use openssl:

Comment: I was wondering how I would set an algorithm.  I am using the identity nugets and in looking at the sample project (that works) I could not find anywhere to set an algorithm.

Comment: So I have figured out that if I use the Development key everything works correctly.  If I set it to a self created key using the below code it fails with the error:
```
            var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(); // generate asymmetric key pair
            var req = new CertificateRequest("cn=PhoenixTest", ecdsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
            var cert = req.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(5));
```